# How to resolve Debug error on VS for Xamarin.Forms UWP app?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms App,
but when I Debug on the Local Machine for UWP, 
Visual Studio prompts me with this Error.
Any solutions solving this problems?

[image]

Update with the e Event Details
[image]

Comment: Could you share the exception stack trace? There is not enough information in the screenshot. You will get the stack trace from event args `e`

Comment: @PrashantC the "e" display the error of "To Impact the native object,enable native code debugging." I already try, Sultion Explorer > Properties > Debug > [ / ] Enable native code debugging ., But the error still same.

Answer (score 0):

This is inside the UnhandledException handler event that Xamarin auto generates. This means that somewhere else in your code there was an exception that was not handled. You did not put it in a try/catch block, so it bubbled all the way up the framework stack to this global handler.

This code intentionally breaks the debugger on this line so that you have a chance to inspect the StackTrace (inside the event args object "e" that was passed into the function.

You should look through the stack trace and find where the actual error is occurring. Then either fix the code or surround it with a try / catch if the exception is expected at that point, and handle it. Depending on the situation, you might want to ignore the exception, inform the user, abort the operation that was being performed or go down a different execution path...

Comment: the "e" display the error of "To Impact the native object,enable native code debugging." I already try, Sultion Explorer > Properties > Debug > [ / ] Enable native code debugging ., But the error still same.